# Use .htaccess to restrict external access to my Intranet

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure this is possible, but its beyond my meager abilities with .htaccess files.

We have an internal php app that we use, we have basic security internally, but dont need to worry too much.  I would like to make it available online for use when staff are out and about.  I would like to have additional security based on htaccess or htpassword files.

Is it possible to write a htaccess file that does the following

- If user is accessing from office.mydomain.com it means they are internal (office.mydomain.com resolves to an internal ip like 192.168.22.22) so allow unimpeded access
- If the user is accessing from outside it will be external.myoffice.com - if this is the case as an added bit of security I would like to use .htaccess and a password file to get the user to enter an apache password.

Can anyone tell me how to write this with .htaccess file?

Update: Thanks for all the answers, I have posted what worked for me as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does do what you want;
<strike>http://codesanity.net/2009/11/conditional-htpasswd-multienvironment-setups/</strike>
<strike>http://tomschlick.com/2009/11/08/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments/</strike>

<strike>https://tomschlick.com/2009/11/08/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments</strike>

Correct address for the resource as of 2022/01/15.
https://tomschlick.com/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments/

Comment: The domain codesanity.net is dead - this answer is no longer useful.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @UlrikH.Kold . Changed the url to the new domain.

Comment: @JRameshFernandez link is now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.
```

to specify the condition of an external IP, or use

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.
```

for the condition of a local IP.

You will just have to integrate these into your existing htaccess rules in a sensible way.

Comment: Thanks but I think this just works for rewrite rules rather than authentication.

Comment: @Toby Allen: To employ this for access control, you need to use the `forbidden|F` flag in the `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
order deny,allow
allow from 192.168.22.0/255.255.255.0
deny from all
```

You can use a subnet mask to make sure the visitors are from the same network. If you need to address another network, just use those IP's (as the server sees them)

Comment: 192.168.22.22 is the ip of my server, not the client.  I need to base it on the url not the ip address.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help.  Toby doesn't want to prevent external users from visiting.  He just wants to give local users special treatment.

Answer (score 2):

To Complete this answer the following Works.

```
#allows everything if its on a certain host
SetEnvIf HOST "^www.mysite.com" external_url
SetEnvIf HOST "^localhost" local_url
Order Deny,Allow

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=external_url
Allow from env=local_url
Satisfy any
```

This pops up a Restricted Area login box if you visit via the www.mysite.com but displays nothing if you are coming locally.